# CSS - How to arrange 9 boxes in 3 columns of 3?

Tags: css, css-float

I don't understand why I can't get these boxes to align horizontally. The second and third columns are beginning underneath the previous column. Can they be arranged horizontally without resorting to moving the columns with `position: relative; bottom: 150px;` type positioning or margins?

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/625nrqj7/

The HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-middle-blocks">
      <div class="submenu-block-1"></div>
      <div class="submenu-block-2"></div>
      <div class="submenu-block-3"></div>
      <div class="submenu-block-4"></div>
      <div class="submenu-block-5"></div>
      <div class="submenu-block-6"></div>
 </div>
<div class="submenu-image-top"></div>
<div class="submenu-image-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.submenu-image-top,.submenu-image-bottom,.submenu-block-1,.submenu-block-    2,.submenu-block-3,.submenu-block-4,.submenu-block-5,.submenu-block-6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

    .submenu-block-1,.submenu-block-2,.submenu-block-3 {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  background: red;
}

    .submenu-block-4,.submenu-block-5,.submenu-block-6 {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background: yellow;
}

    .submenu-image-top,.submenu-image-bottom {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background: blue;
}

    .wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

    .left-middle-blocks {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, but if I understand correctly you can achieve what you want by wrapping each three blocks in a different wrapper and setting:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/npmx2eq6/).

**Snippet:**

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 25px; /* To separate them */
}
.block  {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green; /* To make each square visible */
}
#block-1, #block-2, #block-3 {
    background: red;
}
#block-4, #block-5, #block-6 {
    background: yellow;
}
#block-7, #block-8, #block-9 {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="block-1" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-2" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-3" class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="block-4" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-5" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-6" class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="block-7" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-8" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block-9" class="block"></div>
</div>
```

---

If you want the boxes to stay inline use:

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.wrapper, .block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 15px;
  /* To separate them */
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* To make each square visible */
}
#block-1, #block-2, #block-3 {
  background: red;
}
#block-4, #block-5, #block-6 {
  background: yellow;
}
#block-7, #block-8, #block-9 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="block-1" class="block"></div>
  <div id="block-2" class="block"></div>
  <div id="block-3" class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="block-4" class="block"></div>
  <div id="block-5" class="block"></div>
  <div id="block-6" class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="block-7" class="block"></div>
  <div id="block-8" class="block"></div>
  <div id="block-9" class="block"></div>
</div>
```